# Horizontal and Vertical center to the parent layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating a user profile screen in Android. In this screen have user profile wallpaper and user profile image. Here the grey background is profile wallpaper and red background is going to profile image. I need to set the red bg layout to the horizontal and vertical center of the grey bg layout..

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/rlActivityNotificationsAndProfile">
<include layout="@layout/layout_tool_bar"/>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_wallpaper_container_height"
    android:id="@+id/rlProfileWallpaper"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#646464"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_wallpaper_height">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#A52525">
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/fabEditProfile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/base_ten_dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/base_ten_dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/base_ten_dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/add"
        app:elevation="@dimen/priority_1_elevation"
        app:fabSize="1"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use `android:gravity="center"` for parent `LinearLayout` instead

Comment: Thank you @RomanKolomenskii

Comment: @RomanKolomenskii if OP confirms your solution (did he?), please make an answer from your comment so OP can mark it as completed.

Comment: @AndreaRomagnoli He already did, np :)

Comment: Awesome! I didn't load the page for a while, my fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set your parent LinearLayout's gravity to center (just add 1 line):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/rlActivityNotificationsAndProfile">
<include layout="@layout/layout_tool_bar"/>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_wallpaper_container_height"
    android:id="@+id/rlProfileWallpaper"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#646464"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_wallpaper_height"
        android:gravity="center">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#A52525">
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/fabEditProfile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/base_ten_dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/base_ten_dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/base_ten_dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/add"
        app:elevation="@dimen/priority_1_elevation"
        app:fabSize="1"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```